# C++ boost nuget cannot open file Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am making a C++ project (quite new to C++) and it needs the so called "boost" library. I thought I could add it with a nugget to make my life easier...(`#include <boost\date_time.hpp>` added) but now I am getting this error

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file
>   'libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib'

What is the problem?

Comment: You know, I've never gotten it to work because of the ridiculous disk space requirements.

Answer (score 7):

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file
>   'libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib'

According to the error, you should add the `libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib` library directory to your project configuration. This `.lib` included in the NuGet package `boost_date_time-vc140` or `boost_date_time-vc141`.

Since you are using Visual Studio 2015, **you just need install the NuGet package `boost_date_time-vc140` to your project**, NuGet will add the `libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib` library directory to your project configuration automatically. After installation completed, that error will be resolved.

Besides, since you are use `boost` library in Visual Studio 2015, I suggest that you can use the [`boost-vc140`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost-vc140/), which included many dependencies. So you do not need to add them manually.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the boost library directory to your project configuration, go to the project menu, then properties.

In the property tree go down to 'VC++ Directories' and in the library directories  add \lib64-msvc-12.0 (change the 64 to 32 for 32 bit builds).

I suggest you do this through view->other windows->property manager, then it will be set up for all future projects as well.

Comment: I can't even find where my \lib64-msvc-12.0 file is located... in my packages folder I have \packages\boost.1.65.1.0\lib\native\include\boost

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have a link error is because you installed the header-only NuGet "Boost" package. However, due to an unfortunate design decision, this header-only package also contains header files for Boost libraries that are *not* header-only, such as datetime. With a better design, you would have gotten the error earlier (at compile time).

The "Boost.vc120" and "Boost.vc140" packages contains both header-only libraries and regular compiled libraries; the difference between them is the compiler used.